# C# RedirectStandardInput breaks FTP - Why?

Tags: c#, winapi, console, console-application

I'm searching high and low for a definitive answer on this.

For some reason (some suggest buffers not flushing, others suggest the use of a lower level API) I am finding that output from certain command line applications, specifically ftp.exe, is different when the standard input stream is redirected.

This clearly isolates and demonstrates the difference:

```cs
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    psi.Arguments = " /c ftp";
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    // when false, the ftp prompt is shown            
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true; 

    p.StartInfo = psi;
    p.Start();

    while (true) 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100); 
    }
```

If anyone can put this to bed I'd be extremely grateful.
I am not looking for suggestions to write an FTP client implementation - I simply want to know where the hell "ftp> " is going, and why only when I redirect the standard input stream. Redirecting the other streams (output and error for the uninitiated) doesn't have the same effect.

TIA

Comment: I don't know about the implementation of Windows `ftp`, but it's likely checking whether standard input is pointing to a console and if not, it won't print the prompt. Are you writing a prgram that merely calls out to the `ftp` program, and if so, why not just use an API that provides FTP access?

Comment: FTP itself is not of significance - I want to be able to send input to and catch the output of any console application. For most just redirecting stdio is enough but for others apparently not.